# Improve Asp.net Shop Listview Performance

Tags: asp.net, performance

we have an online shop with about 8000 products. Now its time to improve the performance of product listing / filtering. Currently we store the results of previous searches / listings temporary in the database. The performance of this solution is good enough, but its a pain to extend if we add new search options / filters, etc. What would be the best way to improve performance for such a case? I did not find to much on this topic. Currently i think of two solutions.

1. Caching all products in memory. But how about performance if > 100 users access the in memory object at the same time.
2. Using specialized search engines like lucene.

Comment: Caching should be the fastest approach. But keep in mind that you shouldn't change(add,delete) products while others might list them. That could result in an [Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432393/dataset-in-cache-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-might-not-execut)-Exception. `SyncLock` the object(f.e. DataTable) you want to modify is the easiest way to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to worry about memory in asp.net caching. If your app is running out of memory asp.net caching releases some things from caching memory.
I would go with that solution as I don't think Lucene will be a big help.

Comment: Thanks. But i'm a little worried about concurrency / performance. Lets say i have a List<Product> in memory with 8000 entries. Now many users access the site and i make linq calls like products.Where(p=>name.contains("bla")).OrderBy("bla").Skip(100).Take(50).

Comment: If it's link to objects you don't have any problems with concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

As far as cache you wouldn't cache on a per user basis I dont think.  You may cache the products themselves to prevent round trips to the database.  As far as storing previous searches for the user could this be better done with a cookie?  That way the server will not have to remember that for each user and you will be able to check the cookie on requests.

Comment: No, we don't cache on a user basis. We store the result of previous  searches / listings. If you open a category we look if there's a store result (same category, same sorting, etc.) so that we don't have to do those queries / joins again.