# How to get differences that caused Except to add an IEnumerable?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects

i'm using [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) to check if a `DataTable` in memory is in sync with the table in database.

The background is: this `DataTable` and other frequently used tables are stored in the `Cache` of a WebApplication. But meanwhile i'm convinced that this is not a good approach because it's a source for nasty errors that are difficult to reproduce/debug.

Therefore i've created a function that checks if database and memory are in sync, otherwise an error-log will be created. This works perfectly. If there is a row in memory that is not in database, this row will be shown below *"Difference in database"*, the same applies in reverse. But if rows exist in both datasources(the PK `idRMA`) and some values differ, the log will contain this row in two versions(below "Difference in database" and *"Difference in database"*). It is not easy to see the differences on the first sight.

**Q**: Is it possible to select only the properties that caused `Except` to think that first sequence is not in second?

This is the the complete function(the first lines are relevant):

```
Public Shared Sub CheckRmaMemoryInSyncWithDB()
    Dim inSyncText As String
    Dim color As Drawing.Color
    Dim isInSync As Boolean
    Dim daRma As New ERPModel.dsRMATableAdapters.RMATableAdapter
    Dim tblRma = daRma.GetData()
    Dim memory = (From rma In dsRMA.RMA
                  Where Not rma.IsfiChargeNull
                  Select rma.IdRMA, rma.fiCharge, rma.IMEI, rma.RMA_Number, rma.ModelID, rma.fiCustomer, SI_DPY = If(rma.IsSI_DPYNull, String.Empty, rma.SI_DPY), rma.fiStatus, rma.HasErrors).ToList
    Dim dataBase = (From rma In tblRma
                    Where Not rma.IsfiChargeNull
                    Select rma.IdRMA, rma.fiCharge, rma.IMEI, rma.RMA_Number, rma.ModelID, rma.fiCustomer, SI_DPY = If(rma.IsSI_DPYNull, String.Empty, rma.SI_DPY), rma.fiStatus, rma.HasErrors).ToList
    Dim notInDatabase = memory.Except(dataBase).ToList
    Dim notInMemory= dataBase.Except(memory).ToList

    If notInMemory.Any OrElse notInDatabase.Any Then
        isInSync = False
        inSyncText = "Database and Memory are NOT in Sync! Event-Log created."
        Dim ex As New Exception("Database and Memory are NOT in Sync!")
        Dim errInfo = String.Empty
        If notInMemory.Any Then
            errInfo &= "Difference in memory:" & Environment.NewLine
            Dim memoryInfo = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, notInMemory)
            errInfo &= memoryInfo & Environment.NewLine
        End If
        If notInDatabase.Any Then
            errInfo &= "Difference in database:" & Environment.NewLine
            Dim databaseInfo = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, notInDatabase)
            errInfo &= databaseInfo & Environment.NewLine
        End If
        ErrorLog.WriteError(ex, errInfo)
    Else
        isInSync = True
        inSyncText = "Database and Memory are in Sync, all RMA's are identical in both."
    End If

    Dim master = DirectCast(DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler, Page).Master, ERPMaster)

    color = If(isInSync, Drawing.Color.Green, Drawing.Color.Red)
    master.showStatusMessage(inSyncText, True, color)
End Sub
```

**Note**: I could compare all properties with each other, but i wonder if there is an easier(LINQ) way. Basically i'm looking for a LINQ-way to get only the differences of two Sequences of anonymous types(because i'm only selecting relevant columns of DataRow for this comparison).

**Edit**: I assume that i have to join both on the primarykey(`idRMA`), but how can i select the differences? If the join does not return a result, the ID does not exist in second sequence and it's ok to log all properties. But if there is an appropriate record in second sequence, how can i select the properties that are different?

```
Dim diff = From rmaMem In notInMemory
           Join rmaDB In notInDatabase
           On rmaMem.IdRMA Equals rmaDB.IdRMA
           Select ...... ' i only want to select the properties in `rmaMem` that are different in `rmaDB` '
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stay with following clumsy approach as long as nobody knows a better way. Simply compare them again and show only the values that are different otherwise "equal".

```
Public Shared Sub CheckRmaMemoryInSyncWithDB()
    Dim inSyncText As String
    Dim color As Drawing.Color
    Dim isInSync As Boolean
    Dim daRma As New ERPModel.dsRMATableAdapters.RMATableAdapter
    Dim tblRma = daRma.GetData()
    Dim memory = (From rma In dsRMA.RMA
                  Where Not rma.IsfiChargeNull
                  Select rma.IdRMA, rma.fiCharge, rma.IMEI, rma.RMA_Number, rma.ModelID, rma.fiCustomer, SI_DPY = If(rma.IsSI_DPYNull, String.Empty, rma.SI_DPY), rma.fiStatus, rma.HasErrors).ToList
    Dim dataBase = (From rma In tblRma
                    Where Not rma.IsfiChargeNull
                    Select rma.IdRMA, rma.fiCharge, rma.IMEI, rma.RMA_Number, rma.ModelID, rma.fiCustomer, SI_DPY = If(rma.IsSI_DPYNull, String.Empty, rma.SI_DPY), rma.fiStatus, rma.HasErrors).ToList
    Dim memoryDiff = memory.Except(dataBase).ToList
    Dim databaseDiff = dataBase.Except(memory).ToList

    If memoryDiff.Any OrElse databaseDiff.Any Then
        isInSync = False
        inSyncText = "Database and Memory are NOT in Sync! Error-Log created."
        Dim ex As New Exception("Database and Memory are NOT in Sync!")
        Dim errInfo As String = String.Empty

        'following joins both sequences to detect differences
        'note: completely missing RMA's will be detected later
        Dim diff = From rmaMem In memoryDiff
                 Join rmaDB In databaseDiff
                 On rmaMem.IdRMA Equals rmaDB.IdRMA
                 Select rmaDB.IdRMA _
                 , fiCharge = If(rmaMem.fiCharge = rmaDB.fiCharge, "equal", String.Format("{0}/{1}", rmaMem.fiCharge, rmaDB.fiCharge)) _
                 , IMEI = If(rmaMem.IMEI = rmaDB.IMEI, "equal", String.Format("{0}/{1}", rmaMem.IMEI, rmaDB.IMEI)) _
                 , RMA_Number = If(rmaMem.RMA_Number = rmaDB.RMA_Number, "equal", String.Format("{0}/{1}", rmaMem.RMA_Number, rmaDB.RMA_Number)) _
                 , ModelID = If(rmaMem.ModelID = rmaDB.ModelID, "equal", String.Format("{0}/{1}", rmaMem.ModelID, rmaDB.ModelID)) _
                 , fiCustomer = If(rmaMem.fiCustomer = rmaDB.fiCustomer, "equal", String.Format("{0}/{1}", rmaMem.fiCustomer, rmaDB.fiCustomer)) _
                 , SI_DPY = If(rmaMem.SI_DPY = rmaDB.SI_DPY, "equal", String.Format("{0}/{1}", rmaMem.SI_DPY, rmaDB.SI_DPY)) _
                 , fiStatus = If(rmaMem.fiStatus = rmaDB.fiStatus, "equal", String.Format("{0}/{1}", rmaMem.fiStatus, rmaDB.fiStatus)) _
                 , HasErrors = If(rmaMem.HasErrors = rmaDB.HasErrors, "equal", String.Format("{0}/{1}", rmaMem.HasErrors, rmaDB.HasErrors))
        If diff.Any Then
            errInfo &= "Differences(memory/database):" & Environment.NewLine
            errInfo &= String.Join(Environment.NewLine, diff) & Environment.NewLine
        End If

        Dim memoryIDs = (From rma In memory
                        Select rma.IdRMA).ToList
        Dim databaseIDs = (From rma In dataBase
                       Select rma.IdRMA).ToList
        Dim missingInMemory = databaseIDs.Except(memoryIDs)
        Dim missingInDB = memoryIDs.Except(databaseIDs)
        If missingInMemory.Any Then
            Dim rmaInfo = From rma In dataBase
                       Join idRMA In missingInMemory
                       On idRMA Equals rma.IdRMA
                       Select rma
            errInfo &= "Missing RMA's in memory:" & Environment.NewLine
            errInfo &= String.Join(Environment.NewLine, rmaInfo) & Environment.NewLine
        End If
        If missingInDB.Any Then
            Dim rmaInfo = From rma In memory
                        Join idRMA In missingInDB
                        On idRMA Equals rma.IdRMA
                        Select rma
            errInfo &= "Missing RMA's in database:" & Environment.NewLine
            errInfo &= String.Join(Environment.NewLine, rmaInfo)
        End If
        ErrorLog.WriteError(ex, errInfo)
    Else
        isInSync = True
        inSyncText = "Database and Memory are in Sync, all RMA's are identical in both."
    End If

    Dim master = DirectCast(DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler, Page).Master, ERPMaster)

    color = If(isInSync, Drawing.Color.Green, Drawing.Color.Red)
    master.showStatusMessage(inSyncText, True, color)
End Sub
```

Generates following exemplary output:

```
Differences(memory/database):
{ IdRMA = 25878, fiCharge = equal, IMEI = equal, RMA_Number = equal, ModelID = equal, fiCustomer = equal, SI_DPY = 1207-1104/1206-1105, fiStatus = equal, HasErrors = equal }
Missing RMA's in database:
{ IdRMA = 25882, fiCharge = 1416, IMEI = 004401076362330, RMA_Number = RMA0022725, ModelID = 449, fiCustomer = 49, SI_DPY = , fiStatus = 17, HasErrors = False }
{ IdRMA = 25881, fiCharge = 1416, IMEI = 359419030480338, RMA_Number = RMA0022724, ModelID = 758, fiCustomer = 49, SI_DPY = 1207-1124, fiStatus = 18, HasErrors = False }
```

By the way, this seeming inconsistency was easy to force. Started the application within VisualStudio(Cassini) parallel to the production server and delete/create some test records or change some values here and there.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to create a custom equality comparer as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx). Ultimately you will have to compare the property values somehow and since you're using `Except()` you could keep things consistent and create a custom comparer.

Other then that, you could write a separate function to do the work for you. It's just what you prefer that matters.

EDIT:

This is very rough code, but hopefully might help you out:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p1 = new Person();

            p1.Name = "A";
            p1.Age = 23;

            var p2 = new Person();

            p2.Name = "Ralph";
            p2.Age = 56;

             Diff(p1, p2);
        }

        private static void Diff(Person p1, Person p2)
        {
            var prop = p1.GetType().GetProperties();

            var notMatchingProperties = new List<string>();

            foreach(var p in prop)
            {
                var propName = p.Name;

                var propValue1 = p1.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(p1, null);
                var propValue2 = p2.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(p2, null);

                if (!propValue1.Equals(propValue2))
                {
            notMatchingProperties.Add(propName);        
                }
            }

            foreach (var notMatchingProperty in notMatchingProperties)
            {
            Console.WriteLine(notMatchingProperty);    
            }
            
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

    }
```

I'm not a reflection expert, so if other's could comment on my code, then that would be great.

Ultimately, I'm not sure that caching data is the best method here. You might want to consider storing the information in a database instead. The issue with caching is that, at any moment, the website might get recycled (or restarted) and you can loose your in-memory data.

The other plus of having the data in a database is that you can run a query directly on the database in order to know which properties have changed. In your shoes this is what I'd do - create a table in the database to store the information you have in Cache.

Comment: The default equality comparer works correctly. My problem is: how can i select the different values only with LINQ? So far i'm writing all values into log with `String.Join(Environment.NewLine, notInMemory)`. I want only log the columns that differ.

Comment: Basically i can reduce my question on "how to get differences between two DataRows with LINQ"(although correctly they are anonymous types because i'm only selecting individual columns that are relevant for this comparison).

Comment: Thanks for your added sample. But i'm afraid that this is exactly the approach that i wanted to avoid(more than ever using reflection). +1 for the effort.

Comment: Thanks for being a good sport with the +1. Sorry I couldn't be of more help :( Gave it a go.

Answer (score 2):

This is not answering your question, so downvote away if it's unhelpful, but you might want to think some more about your design.

> this DataTable and other frequently used tables are stored in the Cache of a WebApplication. But meanwhile i'm convinced that this is not a good approach because it's a source for nasty errors that are difficult to reproduce/debug.

This is a red flag.  A `DataTable` is not thread-safe, so you should probably never modify one that is in `Cache`.  Doing so without synchronization will certainly give you nasty errors that are difficult to debug.  And even if synchronization is properly implemented, I'd consider such a design fragile, as it may be easily broken down the line by a less skilled maintenance programmer.

On the other hand, if the DataTable in `Cache` is read-only, I'd suggest that, rather than comparing it with data loaded from the database, you simply replace it by the data from the database - i.e. refresh the cache periodically.  And your application design should expect that it may sometimes find data in the Cache which is not "fresh".

Comment: Thanks. I've already mentioned that i would never use this approach again. But this project is now too far advanced. [It's synchronized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432393/dataset-in-cache-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-might-not-execu) and almost all traps are eliminated. But i'm not 100% convinced, so i've added this function to check on production(if only to reassure myself).

Comment: @Tim, in your linked post you imply that you're only locking during writes. This is insufficient: you need to lock out readers while writing. You can use a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to do so while allow multiple concurrent readers. Even so, handling concurrency when multi-threading is hard to get right, and eliminating "almost" all traps is not enough. I'd suggest you bite the bullet, and redesign it, no matter how far advanced the project is.